# How to override function hoisting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Isn't function abc() `hoisted`? 
Assuming `var abc` and `function abc` both are hoisted which would take precedence?

```
var abc = 10;
console.log(abc);

abc();

function abc(){
    console.log("abc");
}
```

Why does the following code shows error "abc is not a function"?

Comment: It's hoisted then overwritten with a number. It does not matter what has higher precedence, assignment always happens after. And even more - you're checking right after assignment anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is equivalent to writing

```
// hoisted stuff
var abc;
function abc(){
    console.log("abc");
}
// end hoisted stuff
// your code is now
abc = 10; // abc now no longer a function
console.log(abc);
abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the *Function hoisting* feature in Javascript. [You can read more about it here](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/). What it basically means is that if you define a function down in your code, Javascript finds it when it parses the code and assumes it is defined up there in the scope. So this code:

```
abc();

function abc(){
    console.log("abc");
}
```

Works as if you wrote:

```
function abc(){
    console.log("abc");
}

abc();
```

But you have overriden the function by explicitly defining `abc`.
Therefore it is executed assuming that `abc` is the variable you defined.
It won't even work if you call `abc()` after you define the function:

```
var abc = 10;
console.log(abc);

function abc(){
    console.log("abc");
}

abc(); // still an error because abc is still considered a var
console.log(abc); //prints 10
```

By defining a variable with the same name as the function you essentially hidden it. To solve the problem you can give them different names or use function expression (which is like assigning a new value to the variable and doesn't do hoisting):

```
var abc = 10;
console.log(abc); // prints 10

abc = function abc() { // you are assigning a new value to abc
    console.log("abc");
}

abc(); // prints 'abc'
```

Remember that when you use function expressions, the function name is only accessible inside the function body.

```
var a = function b() { console.log('b')}
b() // Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
a() // prints 'b'
```

In this case the function name can however be used inside the function body for recursive calls:

```
function b(x) { return x > 2 ? x * b(x - 1) : 1 }
b(4); // returns 12
```